# Object doesn't support property or method 'wrap' in IE 9

Tags: jquery

I want to wrap some html code inside a div.My code is like this

```
         $x=  $(data).find(list).html().wrap('<div class="new" />');
           alert($x);
```

but this throws an error

```
Object doesn't support property or method 'wrap'
```

in IE 9. Can any one help me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reorder the chain sequence:

```
$x=  $(data).find(list).wrap('<div class="new" />').html();
```

Answer (score 1):

your are usign wrap to html code... you need to convert it to jquery object first to use the wrap method of jquery.

try this

```
 $x=  $($d).wrap('<div class="new" />');
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens since:

```
$(data).find(list).html()
```

returns you the HTML contents of the first element in the set of matched elements or set the HTML contents of every matched element. And in order to wrap, you need a jQuery Object.

So, either you can do this:

```
$d= $(data).find(list);
$x= $d.wrap('<div class="new" />').html();
alert($x);
```

OR

```
$x=  $(data).find(list).wrap('<div class="new" />').html();
alert($x);
```